# Can I force a refresh of a Facebook Object's image URL?

Tags: facebook, image, caching, facebook-opengraph

I have several objects hosted by Facebook that are posted to users' activity logs. The URL for the image is pointed to our content delivery solution, which redirects to a versioned image. This means that the URL can stay constant, but the image might change.

As you can see in this image

[image: Inconsistent Images in Object Browser]

when the image changes, Facebook can still load it correctly (see the og:image column), but the image created in the actual post (see the hover text, which comes from https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php) seems to be cached. I have found that changing the URL by adding a dummy parameter works (and we can do that if necessary), but if there's a way to force Facebook to refresh its cached image, that would be better. Does such a call or method exist?

In similar questions, I have heard that POST calls to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=[ID]&scrape=true
```

can rescrape the data, but I have been unsuccessful with that call (it appears to only scrape the data if the object is self-hosted, is that right?).

There was also something about adding fbrefresh=[ANYTHING] to the URL, but it sounds like that is equivalent to adding a dummy parameter.

Also, using the debugger does not seem to do anything either. I have entered tried:

```
- http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=[ID]
- http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=[ID]&refresh=[ANYTHING]
- http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=[Image URL]
- http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=[Image URL]&refresh=[ANYTHING]
```

Also

```
- http://graph.facebook.com/?id=[ID]&scrape=true
```

All to no avail.

Lastly, does anyone know if/when the cache might be refresh normally? Or would it be expected that the image persists forever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/) says:

```
Updating Objects

When an action is published, or a Like button pointing to the object clicked, Facebook will 'scrape' the HTML page of the object and read the meta tags. The object scrape also occurs when:

    The object URL is input in the Object Debugger
    Every 7 days after the first scrape
    When an app triggers a scrape using an API endpoint

This Graph API endpoint is simply a call to:

POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true
```

When you do this `scrape=true` thing, facebook will go to the og:url parameter and scrape all og parameters on this site. So make sure that this page (og:url) has the appropriate og:image meta tag with the new image url.

If you update the image, you've to rename it (update og:image url) otherwise facebook doesn't know that you've a new image.

Comment: In the end, we've found this to be true, so I have an automation that adds a random parameter to the image URL.

Comment: Hmm I just found this posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache but I'm not sure if it still works.