# FB debugging. Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

I can't use facebook sharing on all inner pages like this: http://www.bazar-cy.com/adv/bmw-e46-330i-2003-sedan-_888/

I have all og tags, but they don't want to work.
Who know where is problem?

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747758/facebook-error-parsing-input-url-no-data-was-cached-or-no-data-was-scraped).