# How to share photos from my website on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have over 1 million photos on my Real Estate site. I want my users to be able to share any photo they like on Facebook.

There are up to 20 photos on one page.

When I put just one photo on a page, I noticed when I go to shared it the photo does not show up in the Facebook share dialogue, but if I go through with the share it actually posts the photo.

I also noticed if I reload the Facebook share dialogue, then the photo shows up.

This seems to be a bug with the Facebook sharing page, because the photos is really there as proved by the post showing it, but the share page does not show the user the photo, therefore they would think it is not working.

Are there any workarounds to get Facebook share dialogue to show the photo every time.

I know about the Facebook debug tool and that works if you have a limited amount of things to share, but with over 1,000,000 photos to share I can't run them all through their debug tool.

Suggestions?

Comment: Please don't down vote a question because you don't know the answer. I am getting answers to this question through a Facebook Developers Group. No one said it is a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. See here for the solutions. This works!

[Facebook Share Dialog does not display thumbnails one first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920519/facebook-share-dialog-does-not-display-thumbnails-one-first-load)